# how to solve page not properly redirecting

Tags: laravel

I am developing a web application using laravel5 framework.I have already uploaded and hosted my site in my remote server.When I try to access the site through the web browser i get an error which says that the page is not redirecting properly.But the site is locally running well.i have tried using .htaccess file to change how i redirect the app by removing the public folder from the url but without success and so i am stack and i need help from anyone how i solve this error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How similar are your local and remote setups? Did you just have to copy the app files to the server or there were more steps involved? Please describe the entire process, because the problem might be with deployment. You offered too little information so far.

Comment: I just copied my entire files and folders from my local machine to the remote server,there were no any other steps involved@bogdan

Comment: I just copied and pasted my files using ftp clients in the same directory as the default index.html available in the root/app/html of the server.When i rename my index.php file to something else it loads the default index.html and the site runs well@bogdan

Comment: And you use the same HTTP server in both environments, configured in the same way (for example: if you're using Apache do you have the same virtual host configuration with the only difference being the domain name)? Please post your the HTTP configuration you use on the server for you application. There are a lot of things that can affect results here, so just saying _"I copied the files and it doesn't work"_ is really not enough.

Comment: I contacted the hosting company to ask whether there is anything to do and they said where i put my site is the correct place and am good to go and they suggest may be the problem is in my code but i have checked everything seems to be ok@bogdan

Comment: Are you using shared hosting or vps/dedicated server?

Comment: I am using shared hosting

Comment: Then you should read [this article](https://medium.com/laravel-news/the-simple-guide-to-deploy-laravel-5-application-on-shared-hosting-1a8d0aee923e), because Laravel is not made to work on shared hosting out of the box. The HTTP server's document root should be the `public` directory, which is something that most hosting providers don't allow to be changed for shared hosting.

Comment: Hi @bogdan,I read article and followed the steps but still the same,thanks for your help I got some new experience